# HTML / Javascript - try to have page pointers as guidance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get this small tutorial to show up the first few 5 seconds pointing to the menu bar on visiting the webpage. Anyone can tell me how I can do that with HTML CSS or Javascript?

I circled it with red of what I wanted on the image.

- should I use an icon
- how do I get it to point to specific point on the web page

[image]

Comment: [URL=http://s32.photobucket.com/user/Valdimir_Pieter/media/help_zpsv6bgcfdp.png.html][IMG]http://i32.photobucket.com/albums/d17/Valdimir_Pieter/help_zpsv6bgcfdp.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Are you trying for this? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Could you please share your sourcecode? And to answer your questions: Yes, i would use an icon or even better a (svg) image. And to answer your second question: To position an element at a specific point use css positioning. You can use "position: absolute; top:100px; left:100px" to position an element 100px from the top and 100px from the left.

Comment: @TimGerhard  well i don't really have a code for the tutorial yet,  only for web page as you can see on the image. what i basically want is that icon with the small text stating what to do for few seconds or showing until the user made a decision(on click) it disappears

Comment: @ManojKumar no not really i want the have this small guide/ pointer with text like on the image i shared to showup on visiting the webpage

Comment: you probably want to have the item visible when the page loads and then have some Javascript set with setTimeout to run some code which hides it after 5 seconds. Not too tricky. To position it you can use some CSS as Tim mentioned. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TimGerhard css code: #guider{
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 100px;
}


html code:
<i id="guider" style="font-size:50px;color:red" class="fa">&#xf102;</i>

as soon as i put the CSS code the icon disappears from  under the menu bar

Comment: @Valdimir Make sure to add z-index: 9999; (this will make it have a higher z-index which will put the element on top of all other elements)

Comment: @Valdimir: check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

One and easy solution is to create an overlay, which will cover the whole page. The purpose of the overlay will than catch the user click, and will destroy itself and also the tooltip.

To create the tooltip just specify the target element, for the tooltip should be created, the easiest way is to use css selector and jQuery.

With jQuery you can than find the target element on the page, get its position and size and according to that create the tooltip element as well.

Here is quick example (also as a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2c0q91np/):

```js
$(function() {
// Find the target element on the page
var target = $(".menu li:nth-child(4n)");
var overlay = null;
var tooltip = null;

// Creates overlay which will handle the first click
function createOverlay() {
 overlay = $("<div class='overlay'></div>").appendTo("body");

 // When user clicks somewhere on the page the overlay will handle the click
 overlay.one("click", destroyOverlay);
}

// Destroys the overlay and tooltip
function destroyOverlay() {
 if(overlay) {
  overlay.remove();
  overlay = null;
 }
 if(tooltip) {
  tooltip.remove();
  tooltip = null;    
 }
}

// Creates tooltip for the target element
function createTooltip(text) {
 // Get the position of the target
 var pos = target.position();
 // Get the height of the target
 var height = target.outerHeight();

 // Create the tooltip
 tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'></div>")
  .html(text)
  .appendTo("body")
  .css({
   "top": pos.top + height + "px",
   "left": pos.left + "px"
  });
}

createOverlay();
createTooltip("Click on one of the tabs to<br>quickly scroll through the page!");

// Desotroy tooltip automatically after 5 seconds
setTimeout(destroyOverlay, 5000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: gray;
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li + li {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.menu li a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.0001);
  z-index: 999;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tooltip:before { 
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-26px);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 13px 26px 13px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Product</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">About the brand</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Join us</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```